# writing a row for each day. mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, loops, mysqli

i've a web form, the user input two dates (YYYY/MM/DD) representing a interval and other informations about an activity on a day.

EXAMPLE: he select 2013/09/12 to 2013/10/02  activity: Swimming

in that case my table will look like:

```
   date     |  activity
2013/09/12  |  swimming
2013/09/13  |  swimming
2013/09/14  |  swimming
2013/09/15  |  swimming
2013/09/16  |  swimming
```

and so on....

i've to write a row with the activity for every day of the date inveral provided by the user

can i do this without iterate through days manually?
i'm using php+mysqli

EDIT: i can't use two columns for start and end date

Comment: How do you store data in your database?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... Do you want to retrieve data or asking about table schema?

Comment: no, i've to WRITE data to DB
my table looks like the one in my axample plus a auto-generated numeric ID and anothe field with additional information.

as i said the user provide two date representing the start and end of a period and an activity via a web form

Comment: Try to work with timestamps... . I'msure this will you help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to make two columns (e.g start_day & end_day).

If it is not possible to change your DB construction you can try this:

PHP:

```
$last_date = $start_date;
$ready = false;
while ($ready === false) {
    $last_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($last_date . ' + 1 day'));+

    // add $last_date to your mysql table here

    if ($last_date == $stop_date) {
      $ready = true;
    }
}
```

It's untested but I hope it works ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I have not enough reputation to do this :/

Comment: unfortunally i can't use two columns. the database already exist and i cannot change it

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 different date columns in your table; one for the start date and one for the end date, you can then add the beginning and end dates of the activity to each of these respectively.

Comment: unfortunally i can't use two columns. the database already exist and i cannot change it

Comment: @JacopoGrassi I guess you could use the current `date` column as a string and store the date range in that column? Such as: `2013/09/12-2013/10/02`.

Comment: not really...the field it's a DATE field, so i can't store a string in it. aside of this there are other applications that use this DB, i can't edit the fields and rewrite all other applications to use a new table.

Comment: @JacopoGrassi Then your current method seems to be the only way. Though it would be more beneficial for you to create a separate table for your new app and then link them if they need to be.

Answer (score -1):

i can give You a clue if You can use PROCEDURES:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dowhile_thing`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dowhile_thing`(dt_start DATE,dt_stop DATE, thing CHAR(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
  `day_name` VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_change` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  thing CHAR(20)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;  


  SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, dt_start, dt_stop)+1  INTO v1;
  WHILE v1 > -1 DO
    INSERT tmp (SELECT DAYNAME( ADDDATE(dt_start, INTERVAL v1 DAY) ),ADDDATE(dt_start, INTERVAL v1 DAY),thing );
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM tmp;  
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;  

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and then call:

```
CALL dowhile_thing('2013-06-10','2013-06-14','swim');
```

result:

day_name |        date_change | thing

Saturday |    2013-06-15  | swim

Friday   |        2013-06-14  | swim

...